# Want to add additional strings to a vector of string vectors in c++

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a dozen string vectors and I want to put all of them into a larger vector and then iterate through to add a string to each of the smaller ones.

Let's say vector 1 has "1" as an element 
vector 2 has "1" and "2" as elements 
vector 3 has "1", "2", and "3" as elements 
... 
vector 12 has "1", "2", ... and "12" as elements

vector "large" has vectors 1-12 in it (or pointers to each of them, whatever is easiest)

I want to go through each element of vector large and add "a" and "b" to vectors 1-12.

Is this possible, or will appending to vector 1 overwrite parts of vector 2?

If the large vector is a vector of pointers to vectors of strings that's fine.

Edit (some of the code, not all of it):

```
vector<vector<string>* > allTypesOfGamesDealt;
vector<string> FB_BJ_BS;
vector<string> BJ_BS;
FB_BJ_BS.push_back("Free Bet");
FB_BJ_BS.push_back("Blackjack");
FB_BJ_BS.push_back("Big Six");
allTypesOfGamesDealt.push_back(& FB_BJ_BS);

BJ_BS.push_back("Blackjack");
BJ_BS.push_back("Big Six");
allTypesOfGamesDealt.push_back(& BJ_BS);

for(int i = 0; i < allTypesOfGamesDealt.size(); ++i)
{
    vector<string> * tempGamesDealt = allTypesOfGamesDealt[i];
        (*tempGamesDealt).push_back("Break");
}
```

^ the problem with that code is that I think I'm adding "Break" to a copy of the vector and not the actual vector.

Comment: Uhhm what please? Please make a small sample in code to clarify!! `std::vector` doesn't store any unique values. If you appen to a vector the values will be added, no matter if they're already are contained in the vector or not.

Comment: Instead of "let's say" and psudocode, please post actual code and actual compiler messages, if there are any,

Comment: `vector 1 = "1";` is not valid C++.  Again, **post real code**.

Comment: "I think I'm adding 'Break' to a copy of the vector and not the actual vector" -- Nope, that code does what you want it to do. I just don't quite see the need for using pointers in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is no, C++ `strings` manage their own memory and will not overwrite anything which has already been allocated to another variable.  I believe they actually allocate a set amount of memory by default and increase it if they need more, rather than allocating exactly as much as they need initially since reallocating memory is relatively expensive so allocating a bit more than needed and not using some is preferable.  Assuming I've understood what you meant,

```
std::vector<std::string> a;
a.push_back("Hell");
a.push_back("World");
a[0].append("o");
```

will have no problems.

EDIT:

Even with the nesting, it will still be fine, for two reasons.  The first is that `vector` generally allocates more memory than it needs like `string` and for the same reason.  Even if you were to hit the capacity and want to add another element, it would use a managed function to reallocate memory, which would ensure that you are not overwriting anything else.

Comment: I've edited the OP to include that I'm doing an additional level of nesting.  Maybe using the word append was a bad choice, I'm pushing back a whole additional string to a vector of type string.

Comment: Ok, the problem is actually somewhere else in my program.  But your statement about the managed function to reallocate memory I was still curious about.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If by "vector" you mean `std::vector`, then no, you won't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>*> vectors = {&v1, &v2, &v3, &v4, &v5, &v6, &v7, &v8, &v9, &v10, &v11, &v12};

for (auto* v : vectors) {
    v->push_back("a");
    v->push_back("b");
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/O4oKul)